# How to Include Angular in a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

To include Angular in rails, I can think of three basic methods:

1. Use `gem 'angularjs-rails'` (which no one seems to do).
2. Download Angular, add it to `/vendor` and manually include it.
3. Use Bower to require it and then manually include.

I suppose the advantage of Bower is just the dependency model but apart from that, why would I pick any one of these over any of the other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good approach is to use [Rails Assets](https://rails-assets.org/).

From their website:

> Rails Assets is the frictionless proxy between Bundler and Bower.
>
> It automatically converts the packaged components into gems that are
>   easily droppable into your asset pipeline and stay up to date.

Comment: Bower is the way to go if you want angular. It gives you a lot more control over the way assets get fed into the rails asset pipeline. You also wont have to wait for gem maintainers to update front end assets to the new version. I have been looking at a large number of angular-rails tutorials recently and they are all using bower.

Comment: You don't have to wait for a new version of the gem to be released with Rails Assets, it will generate the gem directly using the bower's package